# Shopify Storefront API Get Order Line Item price

Tags: shopify, storefront, shopify-app

I'm currently working with Shopify Storefront API and been struggle with this problem lately. 
So when you get OrderLineItem from an Order from the API it only return

- title
- quantity
- variant(product's variant)

It does not contain any information about the line item's price.
For example: i have an OrderLineItem with a product variant had **137**$ as price by the time i created the order. Then i update the product's price to **138**$. The OrderLineItem's price remain $**137** which is correct but the StorefrontAPI does not return any information about the OrderLineItem 's price. Is this a bug or does anyone know where can i find this piece of information ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? You cannot change the price of a product already booked to an order for one thing. You can use the regular API to access a product, and change pricing, but that has nothing to do with the Storefront API.

Comment: I dont want to change anything. I just want to retrieve the product's price when it was ORDERED.

Comment: What does that mean? Why don't you get the order with an API call then? It has the products and their selling price. Why are you confused about this?

Comment: Actually it doesn't. It has the products and their CURRENT selling price, not the price when the product was ORDERED. I'm using Storefront API.

Comment: Storefront API is for front-end presentations. Not for running back-office. If you want back office answers, ie) what product sold in that order and for how much, use the correct API. You are a bit confused it seems.